# Как спозиционировать элементы

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, css3, адаптивная-верстка

Есть готовый пример. В котором на карте указаны поинты [Демо](http://tympanus.net/Development/TooltipStylesInspiration/curved.html).При изменении масштаба страницы - указатели смещаются относительно карты.

Вопрос: Как спозиционировать эти поинты, что бы они не смещались относительно карты при изменении масштаба или как растянуть фон на 100% ширины, но что бы он не съезжал при масштабировании.?

Comment: Вы хотите масштабировать карту с отметками при изменении размеров окна?

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh,да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы верстка не съезжала, нужно чтобы во всех стилях используемых Вашим приложением использовались одни и те же единицы измерения (px/%/vh). А вообще, интерактивные карты сейчас делаются через API, а не статичные изображения

**UPDATE1**

```
.color-3 .container {
    background: transparent url("../img/map.jpg") no-repeat scroll 50% 50% / cover;
    min-height: 1000px;
}
```

Это слишком сложная верстка для Вашего случая. Попробуйте её упростить.

**UPDATE2**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29582571/what-is-the-best-way-to-position-div-markers-over-a-base-image-and-allow-for-r

Comment: Но вопрос был именно как стилизовать.Про то,что они делаются через API я знаю.Но нужен именно тот вариант как в примере.По поводу единиц-менял все на пиксели-разницы нет.

Comment: Я пробовал упросить,усложнить и результата 0.Не писал бы сюда если бы знал как сделать.Свои вариант все уже перепробовал.Если есть конкретные предложения-пишите

Comment: Супер,но есть одна проблема.В том примере сами поинты сделаны через span.У которого стоит ширина и высота в пикселях.Можно ли это как то обойти, не используя вставку символа через content??